# Fb Friend selector in google app engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api

```
<fb:serverFbml style="width: 240px;">
                        <form method="post" action="/friend-selector" id="friend-selector">

                                <script type="text/fbml">
                            <fb:fbml>
                                <fb:friend-selector uid="xxxxx" name="uid" idname="friendselector_s"/>
                            </fb:fbml>
                            </script>
                            <INPUT type="submit" value="submit" class="submit" />
                        </form>
                    </fb:serverFbml>
```

At backend i am trying to get the friends id:

```
def post(self):
  logging.info(self.request.POST)
  ss=self.request.POST[u'friendselector_s']
  logging.info(ss)`
```

So I am geeting error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\__init__.py", line 702, in __call__
    handler.post(*groups)
  File "D:\Workspace\main.py", line 142, in post
    ss=self.request.POST[u'friendselector_s']
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webob\webob\multidict.py", line 302, in __getitem__
    return self._decode_value(self.multi.__getitem__(key))
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webob\webob\multidict.py", line 77, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
```

I am using this code in facebook with google app egine at backend. When collect the data at backend i didnt get the idname. On whole i am not getting selected freind id. 
I also need the data in javscript side also.

Comment: This is not enough information.

Comment: what other information you need. At backend i am trying to get the friends id
`def post(self):
        logging.info(self.request.POST)
        ss=self.request.POST[u'friendselector_s']
        logging.info(ss)`

Comment: Edit your question to post the full code and exact error messages.

Comment: Have you tried using your browser's developer tools to see what fields _are_ being submitted in the form?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the new App Request JavaScript function to send requests, instead of the depreciated FBML version. You can do a simple request using:

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'My Great Request',
}, requestCallback);
```

The [Facebook Requests Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) can help you out further.